How to get array or vector result using SQL injection
pub async fn delete_order(
    pool: web::Data<PgPool>,
    orders_id: web::Path<i32>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, actix_web::Error> {
    let order = sqlx::query_as("????")
        .fetch_one(pool.get_ref())
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            log::error!("Error getting order for deletion: {}", e);
            actix_web::error::ErrorInternalServerError(format!(
                "Error getting order for deletion: {}",
                e
            ))
        })?;

    let new_quantity = order.product.storage_quantity + order.wanted_quantity;
    let product_update = ProductUpdate {
        storage_quantity: Some(&order.product.storage_quantity + &order.wanted_quantity),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    update_product(
        pool.clone(),
        web::Path::from(order.product_id),
        web::Json(product_update),
    )
    .await?;

    sqlx::query("DELETE FROM orders WHERE id = $1")
        .bind(*orders_id)
        .execute(pool.get_ref())
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            log::error!("Error deleting order: {}", e);
            actix_web::error::ErrorInternalServerError(format!("Error deleting order: {}", e))
        })?;

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json("Order deleted successfully!"))
}

SQL BODY:

[
  {
    "product": {
      "id": 67,
      "name": "Product D",
      "price": 5.0,
      "category": "Book",
      "storage_region": "Ontario",
      "storage_street": "asd",
      "storage_country": "Canada",
      "storage_quantity": 5
    },
    "wanted_quantity": 5
  },
  {
    "product": {
      "id": 68,
      "name": "Product D",
      "price": 5.0,
      "category": "Book",
      "storage_region": "Ontario",
      "storage_street": "asd",
      "storage_country": "Canada",
      "storage_quantity": 5
    },
    "wanted_quantity": 5
  },
  {
    "product": {
      "id": 69,
      "name": "Product D",
      "price": 5.0,
      "category": "Book",
      "storage_region": "Ontario",
      "storage_street": "asd",
      "storage_country": "Canada",
      "storage_quantity": 5
    },
    "wanted_quantity": 5
  }
]

structures
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct Product {
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    pub name: String,
    pub price: f64,
    pub category: String,
    pub storage_country: String,
    pub storage_region: String,
    pub storage_street: String,
    pub storage_quantity: i32,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct Order {
    pub product: Product,
    pub wanted_quantity: i32,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct Orders {
    pub orders: Vec<Order>,
}

I need to get data from PostgreSQL and process it into one big vector for further work with it in Rust. In the future, I create several structural data that I want to extract from databases and teach them in one collection for easier manipulation. Are there any limitations or difficulties associated with this process? What approaches or libraries are recommended to use to implement this task? In particular, I want to understand how to properly organize database queries and processing of results in such a way that all received data can be easily combined into one common vector
